# Desktop browser that supports Fido U2F over CCID

Tags: web-browser, smartcard, u2f

Is there any browser that supports Fido U2F over CCID for smart cards? As far as I can see Firefox and Chrome only support U2F over HID, and only Chrome for Android (with Google Authenticator2) supports U2F over NFC.

Why is no desktop browser supporting U2F over CCID for smart cards? Is support planned or in development?